# How to change scientific notation style in gnuplot?

Tags: printf, gnuplot

I'd like to place some labels on the plots with numeral text in scientific notation. My problem is that gnuplot prints labels like 2e+003, which is correct, but I prefer a shorter form, e.g. 2e3. **How can I shorten the notation?**

Here's what I get:

[image: An example of the detailed behavior]

A script to reproduce the image above:

```
reset
labelpositions = "1000 2000 5000 10000"
do for [labelposition in labelpositions] {
set label at sqrt(labelposition+0),labelposition+0 sprintf("%.0e",labelposition+0)
}
p [0:120] x**2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a shorter notation use `gprintf` and the `%t` and `%T` formats:

```
reset
labelpositions = "1000 2000 5000 10000"
do for [i in labelpositions] {
    set label at sqrt(i+0),i+0 gprintf("%.0te%T", i+0) offset 1
}
p [0:120] x**2
```

Comment: I was mentally disabled to realise that gprintf does the trick, thanks! Good to know that if I'd like to print "some text 2e3", I shall use `sprintf("some text %s",gprintf("%.0te%T", i+0))`.